# Amplitude shift keying using NMOS cascode transistor configuration

Tags: operational-amplifier, digital-modulation, cascode, ads, amplitude-modulation

[image: I am trying to design Amplitude Shift Keying (ASK) using NMOS transistors in a cascade configuration as shown in the figure]. I am using 50 MHz as a carrier signal and a pulse signal as the data signal. Unfortunately, I could not get my desired modulated ASK signal. I am using ADS software. Kindly guide me on how to do it. You can share related materials or papers.
I have attached the modulated output with the pulse signal and carrier signal (100MHz). The output is inverted I do not know why?....because it should give output high when the data pulse signal is high and output low when the data pulse signal is low.

[image]

Comment: What did you get?

Comment: a random signal output

Comment: The output inverted makes perfect sense from the topology used. Why dont you just invert the data signal?

Comment: @NaqeebUllah please post a picture of your signal and explain where you got the schematic from and what MOSFETs you used.

Comment: @Linkyyy I just want to have output when my data is 1 (switched on) and have no output voltage when the data is 0 (switched off). therefore i am using the configuration as shown in figure. my data is pulse (5MHz) and ac input is 50MHz

Comment: @Andyaka you can find the schematic in a paper "60 GHz Low Power 1.5 Gb/s ASK Transmitter in 90 nm CMOS with On-Board Yagi-Uda Antenna". i am interested in design the ASK modulator

Comment: _"I just want to have output when my data is 1 (switched on) and have no output voltage when the data is 0 (switched off)"_ - well you cant do that with this topology.

Comment: @Linkyyy but I have seen in a research paper they have done. is there any alternative to get on-off keying amplitude modulation??

Comment: What research paper?

Comment: paper title"60 GHz Low Power 1.5 Gb/s ASK Transmitter in 90
nm CMOS with On-Board Yagi-Uda Antenna